# Build a HAR file using only client side code?

Tags: har

Is that possible? I know I can extract some timing data using the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API), but that's not enough. Also know that I can use a proxy like Browsermob Proxy, but I was wondering if I could do the same with just client side code (JS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something using the Resource Timing API might be what you are looking for? I am looking for an answer to a similar issue and I found this article which has been useful:

http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/an-introduction-to-the-resource-timing-api/

You can see the code that implements the API here:

https://github.com/andydavies/waterfall/blob/master/waterfall.js

I hope this is helpful.